# Table being scanned multiple times for select/count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I inherited some un-optimized SQL Server queries. There is a lot going on above this code sample, but this is where 75% of the query execution is coming from. Because in each of these select/counts, table 1 is being scanned. Is there a way to get table 1 scanned for everything in one go. Notice were counting based off of column3, but the values in the where clause are coming from column4. This makes it a little more tricky than other solutions I have seen.

```
SELECT 
    table1.column1,
    table1.column2
    (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT table1.column3)
     FROM table1
     WHERE table1.column4 = 'value') AS 'count of values'
    (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT table1.column3)
     FROM table1
     WHERE table1.column4 = 'value2') AS 'another count of different values'
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    table1.column55 IN ('random value')
```

This goes on for about 6 more times. Meaning there are about 6 more `SELECT COUNTs` than shown, but the format is the same.

Comment: This is expected. You have *3* references to `table1` in 3 different `FROM`s and so `table1` needs to be scanned, or at least seeked against, for all of those.

Comment: The subqueries you have here aren't correlated; is that intentional? If so, I'm not sure there's much you can do about this. You can't window a `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`.

Comment: You can do a `SELECT DISTINCT column4, column3 FROM table1 WHERE column4 IN ('value', 'value2')` in a preparatory step, then again `DISTINCT` and `COUNT` over that; in anything but the worst case (all values unique) this is likely to give a speedup. The counts themselves can be sped up considerably by creating a columnstore index on `column3` and `column4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is obfuscated so much it is kind of hard to tell what is going on but I think something like this should be close. It will at least only query table1 a single time instead of over and over.

```
with MyCounts as
(
    select Value1 = count(distinct case when table1.column4 = 'value' then table1.column3 end)
        , Value2 = count(distinct case when table1.column4 = 'value2' then table1.column3 end)
    from table1
)

select t.*
    , c.Value1
    , c.Value2
from table1 t
cross join MyCounts c
```

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. Theres roughly 300 lines before even this section. Either way I took your suggestion, tweaked it a bit, and it cut down the time! Thank you so much!